# Laravel return array value from app/config/package folder

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Hi I am using a laravel package https://github.com/greggilbert/recaptcha and I have published the config files where I need to store my public and private keys for my recaptcha. I want to call this elsewhere in my app in an attempt to process this via AJAX . I've tried to call this as

`dd(Config::get('packages.greggilbert.recaptcha')['public_key']);`

however this returns as null. The array is kept in the following folder:

`app/config/packages/greggilbert/recaptcha/config.php`

the array is built as so:

```
<?php

return array(


    'public_key'    => 'publickey',
    'private_key'   => 'privatekey',

    'template'      => '',

    'driver'    => 'curl',

    'options'       => array(

        'curl_timeout' => 1,

    ),

    'version'       => 2,

);
```

Any ideas how I can retrieve the `public_key` value??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieving configs from a package works a bit different. You use a so-called *namespace*:

```
Config::get('recaptcha::public_key');
```

Comment: oh i see, thanks! i will accept when the timer runs out.